# MouseEvents and MouseDragEvents together

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, mouseevent

Okay, So I've basically been pulling my hair out all day trying to make sense of MouseEvents and MouseDragEvents. From what I have gathered, when a full drag is started (MouseDragEvent) is prevents any MouseEvent from being triggered.

Basically, I'm making a checker game and I want it to be so that when a piece is clicked and dragged, the piece is translated so that it appears to follow the mouse. For this, it make sense to use MouseEvents. But doing it this way makes it difficult to tell where the piece was dropped. The only way I can conceive doing it is by calculating the translate relative to the mouse's scene X and Y and the starting X of the Board. This works fine, but As soon as I add anything to the left of the board it get a bit wonky.

Alternatively, I can use a MouseDragEvent which makes it much easier to drop the piece because I can just use the OnDragDropped handler, but doing it this way causes the piece to stop following the cursor. Is there any way to make the piece follow the cursor while using MouseDragEvents?

Thanks, I'm new to JavaFX and Java in general, so I appreciate any help!

Comment: It's a bit difficult to answer your question (which technically isn't really a question...) without knowing something about how you have organized your code. How are you representing the pieces and the board visually? Can you create a [MCVE] that just shows how your board and pieces are set up and how you have tried to implement the drag and drop?

Comment: You need to coordinate your mouse drag with the coordinates provided by the MouseMove event. Yes...the MouseMove event is firing while you're dragging and simply because...it's moving. Both utilize the same listener.